# Placeholder background/image while waiting for full image to load?

Tags: css

I have a few images on my page. I'm finding that the page starts to render before the images have been loading (which is good), but that the visual effect is not great. Initially the user sees this:

```
 --------hr--------
 text
```

Then a few milliseconds later the page jumps to show this:

```
--------hr--------
[           ]
[   image   ]
[           ]
text
```

Is there a simple way that I can show a grey background image of **exactly the width and height** that the image will occupy, until the image itself loads?

The complicating factor is that I don't know the height and width of the images in advance: they are responsive, and just set to `width: 100%` of the containing div. This is the HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="myimage.jpeg" />
<div class="caption">caption</div>
</div>
img { width: 100% }
```

Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate the basic problem: http://jsfiddle.net/X8rTB/3/

I've looked into things like [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), but I can't help feeling there must be a simpler, non-JS answer. Or is the fact that I don't know the height of the image in advance an insurmountable problem? I do know the aspect ratio of the images.

Comment: Make an empty div with a grey background and set dimensions, then add the image as `background-image`?

Comment: Tried that as follows, but it doesn't actually seem to do anything: `ul.options li { background: url(/media/img/cont/filler.png); background-size: 100% 100%; }`

Comment: Richard, don't use a list item, use a div in place of the `<img/>`, and then give it set dimensions (`height: 200px; width:300px;`) and it should work

Comment: You can't know the width and height of the image until you have loaded the image. It's impossible show the placeholder with exact dimensions that are unknown. If you know the aspect ratio in advance then it's possible the calculate the height.

Comment: height and width attribute for img are basicly made for this (spare ressource for calculating img size and avoid content to jump once image is loaded). You could even update those attributes on server side and inject it in the the tags before the page/html is sent to the browser. if your server runs php : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 36):

Keep in mind - the previous answers that recommend using a *div* background approach will change the semantic of your image by turning it from an *img* into a *div* background. This will result in things like no indexing of these images by a search crawler, delay in loading of these images by the browser (unless you explicitly preload them), etc.

A solution to this issue (while not using the *div* background approach) is to have a wrapper *div* to your image and add *padding-top* to it based on the aspect ratio of the image that you need to know in advance. The below code will work for an image with an aspect ratio of 2:1 (height is 50% of width).

```
<div style="width:100%;height:0; padding-top:50%;position:relative;">
  <img  src="<imgUrl>" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;">
</div>
```

Of course - the major disadvantage of this approach is that you need to know the aspect ratio of the image in advance.

Comment: This is the best solution, SEO-wise.

Comment: This only occupies the area, but does not show a placeholder background image as requested by OP. Simply adding a `background-image` to the container div wouldnt work either when the image itself contains transparent areas.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of referencing the image directly, stick it within a DIV, like the following:

```
<div class="placeholder">
    <div class="myimage" style="background-image: url({somedynamicimageurl})"><img /></div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.placeholder {
    width: 300;
    height: 300;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url('my_placeholder.png');
}
```

Comment: This relies on the non-placeholder image not being transparent, doesn't it?

Answer (score 14):

There is a really simple thing to check before you start looking into lazy-loading and other JavaScript. Make sure the JPEG images you are loading are saved with the 'progressive' option enabled!

This will cause them to load the image iteratively, starting with a placeholder that is low-resolution and faster to download, rather than waiting for the highest resolution data before rendering.

Comment: i'm new in html. how do you enable 'progressive' option?

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple...

This scenario allows to load a profile photo that defaults to a placeholder image.

You could load multi CSS background-image into an element. When an avatar photo fails, the placeholder image appears default of div.

If you're using a div element that loads via a CSS background-image, you could use this style:

```css
#avatarImage {
    background-image: url("place-holder-image.png"), url("avatar-image.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="avatarImage"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is about images failing to load, while OP is about placeholder images to show *while loading*.

Comment: Nice! It seems this works in reverse. The first specified image is the one that loads if both are present, so the second specified image should be the fallback. So the slight change to your answer would be `url("avatar-image.png"), url("place-holder-image.png");`

Comment: @UcheOzoemena that's exactly what I came for tho I use a 3px wide data uri as placeholder which mimicks the gradient of the actual image sufficiently but ways only couple bytes 

Answer (score 5):

Feel *free* to copy this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    });
</script>

<body>
    <image src="example.example.example" alt="example" id="image" style="background-color:blue;">
</body>
```

I got this from here: *[Preloader keeps on loading and doesnt disappear when the content is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983243/preloader-keeps-on-loading-and-doesnt-disappear-when-the-content-is-loaded)*.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all solutions already mentioned, the last solution would be to hide the document until everything is loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  document.body.classList.add('loaded');
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
}
body.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8075/8449869813_1e62a60f01_b.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-1.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-2.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-3.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-4.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-5.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-6.jpg" />
</div>
```

Or show some animation while everything is loading:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  document.body.classList.add('loaded');
});
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35px);
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body :not(.loader) {
  opacity: 0;
}

body .loader {
  display: block;
}

body.loaded :not(.loader) {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.loaded .loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8075/8449869813_1e62a60f01_b.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-1.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-2.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-3.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-4.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-5.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.nla.gov.au/sites/default/files/pic-6.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: What does "`/* Safari */`" apply to? How many lines? Which lines?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of, to minimize the jump effect on your text, is to set `min-height` to where the image will appear, I would say - set it to the "shorter" image you know of. This way the jump will be less evident and you won't need to use lazyLoad or so... However it doesn't completely fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one naive way of doing it,

```css
img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

You can manipulate the values, but it creates a very light border around the image that doesn't push the contents. Images can load at whatever time they want, and you get a good user experience.

Update Remarks: `rgba(#000, 0.1)` is not a proper css value.

Comment: A nice idea, but in practice it does not work. You can test it with an image loaded from src="http://placehold.it/150x150" since they tend to load quite slowly (free service, that's why). Since the DOM does not yet have an object with any size assigned, the box shadow just renders as a small dot (since there is nothing yet to 'shadow')

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did with [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), but it's just CSS:

```css
img {
  @apply bg-no-repeat bg-center;

  body.locale-en & {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text x='50%' y='50%' style='font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'>Loading…</text></svg>");
  }

  body.locale-fr & {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text x='50%' y='50%' style='font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'>Chargement…</text></svg>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately all of the accepted answers had some major drawbacks for me: SEO-unfriendly, additional divs, calculating aspect ratio, etc.

My solution is quite simple, works for my project and I could not find major problems so far.

```html
<img
  src="my_full_image.jpg"
  alt="my image"
  style="
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,...[base64_placeholder_image]...');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;"
  width="600"
  height="900"
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

**how it works / advantages:**

- the placeholder-image is loaded as background-image. It is inlined as base64-png, so it loads together with the html-markup. I use 20px-width low-res-placeholder-images
- the placeholder-image is shown as soon as the html-markup is loaded and until the full image is loaded
- modern browsers will apply a blur-effect to low-res images by default - so there is no need for additional css-filter blur technics
- the width and height parameters are **optional** in that setup; however they enable the browser to determine the aspect ratio and prevent cumulative layout shift
- with=100%, height=auto is for responsive sizing
- lazy-loading is **optional**; it optimizes the loading time of the page (if image is not directly in viewport on page load)

Comment: One additional question: when I observe the network communication via DevTools, I can see that it still downloads all images, immediately, even those that are currently not in viewport. Did I understand something wrong? Here's an example: w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_loading

Comment: The placeholder image will be loaded instantly on page load together with all the other html-markup (because it is inlined). This is intended and only some bytes. The full-size image shall be loaded when entering in viewport (due to loading="lazy"). Please note that older browsers do not support loading="lazy".

Comment: What if I don't know the size in advance like you put   width="600"
  height="900". I can pass size from server side. How can I put that into css?

Comment: Width and height only need to reflect the correct aspect-ratio to prevent cumulative layout shift. They are optional (but strongly recommended). How to pass the values from server-side to the HTML / CSS depends heavily on your setup and framework (next.js? astro? pure react? ...)

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property on the `img` selector, one can set the value to match the image's ratio (**width** / **height**) and apply a `background` property to fill the area.

Below is a +7MB image and the left one has a fixed *aspect-ratio* and so it occupies layout space when before it gets loaded.

I've also simulated a network delay by setting the `src` with a slight delay of 1 second

```js
const imgURL = 'https://live.staticflickr.com/7151/6760135001_ddc2c15fd3_6k.jpg';

// delay image loading (simulating slow network handshake)
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(node => node.src = imgURL)
}, 1000)
```

```css
body{ display:grid; grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr; }

img{ 
  width: 45%;  
  background: red;
}

img.aspect{  
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <img class='aspect' />
  <p>with aspect-ratio</p>
</aside>

<aside>
  <img />
  <p>normal</p>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the width and height of the images in the developer tools console, for example in Chrome you can click the cursor icon in the developer tools console and when you hover on the page it will highlight all the properties of the elements in the page.

This will help you find the width and height of the images, because if you hover on top of your images it will give you the dimensions of the image and other more properties. You can also make an individual *div* for each image and make the *div* relative to the images width and height. You can do it like this:

The main *div* will contain the images and also the background-div which is below the image.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class=".mainDiv">
        <div class="below"></div>
        <img src="https://imgix.bustle.com/uploads/image/2020/2/13/da1a1ca4-95ec-40ea-83c1-4f07fac8b9b7-eqb9xdwx0auhotc.jpg" width="500"/>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.mainDiv {
  position: relative;
}

.below {
  position: absolute;
  background: #96a0aa;
  width: 500px;
  height: 281px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

The result will be that `.below` will be below the image and so when the image has trouble loading the user will instead see the grey `.below` div. You cannot see the `.below` div because it is hidden below the image. The only time you will see this is when the loading of the image is delayed. And this will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a way. But you will need to use JavaScript for it.

The HTML:

```js
img = document.getElementById("img")
text = document.getElementById("text")
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEWIiIhYZW6zAAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    text.innerHTML = "Loaded but image is not";
});

window.onload = function() {
    img.src = "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190913002133/body-onload-console.png";
    text.innerHTML = "Image is now loaded";
};
```

```css
#img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<hr>

<img id="img" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190913002133/body-onload-console.png">

<p>Here is the Image</p>
<p id="text">Not Loaded</p>
```