# Replace CSS background when image is loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, get

I have a placeholder background image that i want to replace **after** its loaded.

```
$.get("BIG-IMAGE-URL").done(function(data){
    $('.MY-DIV-CLASS').css('background-image', 'url("BIG-IMAGE-URL")');
});
```

Does anyone know how to make a simple function like this?

Comment: JS seems overkill for this as you can just use CSS/HTML and save having to write and make another AJAX call for every required image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748750/placeholder-background-image-while-waiting-for-full-image-to-load

Comment: Are you trying to only load the image if it's available? If so this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asynchronously-load-images-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your big image with javascript, and set the CSS background in the load event handler.

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // set background here
  $('.MY-DIV-CLASS').css('background-image', 'url("bigImage.png")');
}, false);
img.src = 'bigImage.png'; // Set source path
```

Source: [MDN Using_images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)

Additionally, here is a similar solution using jQuery [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/1799146)